# How to go to new line in text mode assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, vga

I am currently making my own operating system. As I will be going into 32bit mode at some point, I am going to need to print to the screen without interrupts as they won't exist.

Here is my code so far:

```
org 0x7c00            ; add to offsets
xor ax, ax            ; make it zero
mov ds, ax            ; ds=0
mov ss, ax            ; stack starts at 0

cld

mov ax, 0xB800        ; Ax = address of video memory
mov es, ax
xor di, di


mov si, msg         ; load msg into si
call print            ; call thr print function

hlt

print:
  mov ah, 07h

printchar:
  lodsb               ; Hear we load a letter from si
  stosw
  cmp al, 0
  je done
  jmp printchar

done:
  ret                 ; return





msg db "Hello, World", 0   ; msg = 'test'
xpos   db 0
ypos   db 0


times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; make sure file is 510 bytes in size
dw 0xaa55             ; write boot signiture
```

When looking at the [documentation](https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_UI), I know that to set the position of the character, I have to get `position = (y_position * characters_per_line) + x_position;`.

The only problem is, it doesn't seem to work. Even if I add one to the address so it is `0xB801`, it does not move the text by one character. Instead, I get this: [image].

What is going on here and how am I meant to print a character on a new line and also increment the x position by one?

Comment: Please tag your questions properly so we don't keep having to edit them for you.  It says right in the description for [tag:assembly] that it's too vague on its own.  x86 is not the only architecture, and a bootloader is very different from 64-bit code running under Linux, for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry! I wasn’t sure what other tags to use. Thanks for letting me know in the future.

Comment: @PeterCordes, What do you mean by `so 16 bytes or 8 characters`? Also what registers am I meant to use to specify the position?

Comment: You can use whatever registers you want.  You're currently using DI as the byte offset relative to the VGA base (which you put in `es`).

Comment: What answer says... and in standard 80x25 (or other 80x??) text mode the next line is at +160 bytes (80*2), so lines start at real-mode addresses `B800:0000`, `B800:00A0`, `B800:0140`, `B800:01E0`, etc... (of course you can compose that address by many other variants in real mode, like `B800:01E0` is also `B81E:0000`, etc... but you probably want to keep segment fixed to `B800` and move around only offset part. In 32b flat mode there's no ambivalence, `B_8000` is addressable only in this way (without creating memory maps aliasing that region also elsewhere...).

Comment: @Ped7g So you mean if I move the address by 0x0001, that’s moving by 16 bytes where as 0x0000::0001 is one byte?

Comment: +1 in segment is +16 in physical address. In 16b real mode physical addresses are 20 bits "wide", and they are composed as ((segment<<4) + offset) ... i.e. ((1<<4) + 0) = 16. And +1 on offset part will move you by one byte (in VGA text mode that means alternating between letters and attributes, common bug to forget to do the final \*2 to the "position").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters in VGA text mode are 2 bytes; one for the character and one for the attributes.  +1 bytes is not the start of a character.

But you're not adding 1 to the address, you're adding 1 to the segment base (`0xB801`), so you're going forward 16 bytes or 8 characters relative to the 0,0 position at the start of VGA memory at linear address 0xB8000.

One character forward would be `add di,2`, because your current code is using es:di to store into VGA memory.  (Or start with `mov di,2` instead of zeroing it.)

You wouldn't have to deal with segmentation if you switched to 32-bit protected mode with a flat 32-bit address space.  You're not using any BIOS calls now, so you could.